# CSS transform / rotate text of dynamic width with line above

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to achieve something simple but somehow complicated with CSS, I would like to rotate a number of labels that need to be top aligned with a top border, of equal widths along the lines of:

[image: rotated text]

There are a few issues that are causing conflicting issues (fixing one breaks the other):

1. The text will be of varying/dynamic width
2. The labels need to remain of an equal width - 32px (not wider)
3. They need to align along the 'top', floated along other elements

See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kemuleb/edit?html,css,output):

html:

```
<div class="label">
  <span class="label-text">Hello</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.label {
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.label-text {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 64px;
}
```

Which results in:

[image: jsbin screenshot]

Which is close, but I'm unable to get the bar narrower without affecting the text within. Once I start playing with widths, the rotation seems to cause all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but it involves positioning and knowing some heights.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.label {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 1em;
  height: 150px;
  /* you need to know the max height  or you get overflow */
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.label-text {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="label">
  <span class="label-text">I'm short and OK</span>
</div>
<div class="label">
  <span class="label-text">I'm waaay too long to be contained in this area.</span>
</div>
```